# как передать input

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как передать содержимое этих input в php без кнопок и перезагрузки страницы. Вроде как можно через ajax. Пробовал, ничего не получилось.

```
<input type="text"  name="step1" />
<input type="text"  name="step2" />
<input type="text"  name="step3" />
<input type="text"  name="step4" />
<input type="text"  name="step5" />
```

Comment: А как без кнопки ты собираешься определять, что пора отправлять форму на сервер? После какого события это должно происходить?

Comment: $('#text').bind('input', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax.php', 
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {text: $('#text').val()},
        success: function(data){
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
});

Comment: только не работает почему то

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, у тебя не хватает атрибута `value` на инпутах. Во-вторых, в любом случае нужно какое-то действие (пусть даже неявное), чтобы отправить. В простейшем случае эти инпуты - часть формы (внутри тэга `<form>`), и после сабмита (по кнопке или еще как) они станут элементами `$_GET`/`$_POST` и `$_REQUEST` в php.

Альтернативно, без перезагрузки страницы, повесь отправку на любое событие (не обязательно клик на кнопку), какое тебе нужно, а дальше собери значения полей с формы с помощью javascript и отправь тем или иным методом. Для упрощения можно использовать jQuery примерно так:

```
function submitForm(){
    var form = $("селектор формы"),
        url = form.attr("action"),
        formData = form.serializeArray();
    $.post(url, formData).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
$("какой-то селектор").on("какое-то событие", submitForm);
```

**P.S:** используй `on` вместо `bind`. И делать отправку вводимого в текстовое поле на событие `input` без *debouncing/throttling* может заставить лагать твой интерфейс и создавать излишнюю нагрузку на бэк. Суть *debouncing/throttling* - это сделать более редкой отправку данных, т.е. не прямо после каждого введенного/удаленного символа, а с некоторой паузой после последнего события (*debouncing*) или просто раз в какое-то время (*throttling*).